# Factoring $x^4 - 16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I was following a calculus tutorial that factored the equation $x^4-16$ into $(x^2 +4) (x+2)(x-2)$.

Why is the factorization of $x^4-16 = (x^2 + 4)(x+2)(x-2)$ rather than $(x^2 - 4)(x^2 +4)$?

Comment: Hint:  What happens if you factor $x^2 - 4$?

Comment: Is $x^4-16$ an equation or a polynomial?

Comment: It's called a multi-step problem.

Answer (score 4):

That is, since $(x^2+4)(x+2)(x-2)$ is the simplest form of the equation $x^4-16$, rather than $(x^2-4)(x^2+4)$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $x^4-16=(x^2)^2-4^2\\
=(x^2-4)(x^2+4)\\
=(x+2)(x-2)(x^2+4)\\
=(x-2)(x+2)(x+2\color{red}i)(x-2\color{red}i)$

Answer (score 1):

They are *both* factorizations of $x^4-16,$ but $(x^2+4)(x^2-4)$ is a less complete factorization.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could factor all the way to complex roots:

$$x^4-16 = (x^2-4)(x^2+4) = (x-2)(x+2)(x-2i)(x+2i).$$